# Dask worker resources attribute values

Tags: attributes, resources, dask, worker

Are resource value limited to numbers? With all the example I have seen, it is always a number and as per doc it is converted to float. So we cannot have something like resources={'GRAPHIC_CARD': 'NVIDIA Quadro M5000M'}. Is that rue ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe resources have numerical values.  You could do something like:

```py
{'NVIDIA Quadro M5000M': 1, 'Tesla V100': 2}
```